# Getting Error while doing a scattering region calculation using transiesta in SIESTA version 4.1.5

Tags: siesta

I am using SIESTA version 4.1.5, when doing scattering region calculation using transiesta iam getting error as:

```
Electrode: Left is a Gamma-only calculation, this is not feasible.
Electrode: Left is a Gamma-only calculation, this is not feasible.
Erroneous electrode setup, check out-put
Stopping Program from Node:   19
```

How may I fix this error?

Comment: No sir this is not the answer

Comment: Yes it is. I think you have not read all my comments. If you were to show the input and output *as code* in the question I would be able to explicitly show you the problem. Having links to input/output is not stable going forward since new users won't be able to see the content, so please update the other question.

Comment: If you would like to attach input and output files, please put as many of them into the question's post as possible, in `code` blocks. Anything that doesn't fit, can be uploaded to a folder called "10297" in [this repository](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters). 10297 is the number in this question's URL. I have removed the part of your question that has links to files in Google Drive.